# The exe file build through cmake throws an error on another computer. (missing dll error)

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, sdl, static-linking

On the computer where it was built, it runs fine, but on other computers an error saying that the DLL could not be found appears.

this is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

find_library(SDL_MIXER_LIBRARY
  NAMES SDL2_mixer
  HINTS
    ENV SDLMIXERDIR
    ENV SDLDIR
  PATH_SUFFIXES lib
)

target_link_libraries(SpaceCadetPinball SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_mixer)

target_compile_options(SpaceCadetPinball PUBLIC -lmingw64  -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -mwindows -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -static-libgcc)
```

error list:

> SDL2_mixer.dll
> libstdc++-6.dll
> libwinpthread-1.dll
> libgcc_s_seh-1.dll

How do I build these as static libraries so that I can use them on other machines?

Comment: SDL and your application need to be built as static and using static runtime for this to work. It may be easier to just create an installer for your application packaging all the required dlls and avoid the issue. I have CMake generate a NSIS based installer for my applications at work.

Comment: You don't need to build them as static libraries, just distribute them with your exe.

Comment: "How do I build these as static libraries" - For every library building it statically is a **separate problem**, so it should be asked in **separate question post**. Take one library, then search for how to build it statically. If you cannot find suitable instructions, then ask about that library specifically. Then take another library, and repeat the procedure for it. And so on.

Comment: Your `find_library` call set the variable `SDL_MIXER_LIBRARY`, which is then unused.